# 2006 Chev Cobalt Wont go forward

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, cobalt

My 2006 Chev Cobalt will go in reverse but not forward. Any thoughts? Backed it in driveway on a Friday, got in Saturday Morning and it wouldnt go.

Comment: Welcome to the site. ***"Any thoughts"*** is rather vague and won't get you a good answer. Assuming you want to know how to resolve this, please use the [edit] feature to add additional details for mileage, last transmission service, transmission fluid level, any shifting problems prior to this issue, if the *check engine* or *service* light is on, if you have had the codes read. All these details will help us answer your question.

Comment: If an automatic, have you checked the fluid?

Comment: Is the E-brake disengaged?

Answer (score 1):

In the transmission your car has, a frequent issue I saw as a GM trans tech was the oil pressure tubes cracking that provide pressure to the forward clutch. They are above the filter on the bottom of the trans. When these break, the car will have reverse but no forward.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an automatic or manual transmission?
Have you confirmed that it will still go in reverse, but not forward?

If an automatic:
Is it making any noises or is there any movement in the car as you cycle forward/backward through the transmission (P, N, D, etc.)?

If manual:
If you depress the clutch pedal, can the car roll easily?

Is the CEL (check engine light) or any other warning lamp on?

There are many possibilities here, but without more detail it's really difficult to help you troubleshoot.